# Why does a right arithmetic shift of 3 to the binary sequence "0110 0100" lead to "1110 1100" instead of "0000 1100"?

Tags: bit-shift

In a textbook I'm looking at, it asks me to do an arithmetic right shift to the binary sequence `0110 0100` by 3 (`a >> 3`). I thought it was `0000 1100` as I would add 3 zeros at the right considering the most significant bit is `0` (or is it `01`?), but the answer key says the correct answer is `1110 1100`.

An arithmetic shift is defined as follows:

> An arithmetic right shift fills the left end with k repetitions of the most significant bit...

As the most significant bit in `0110 0100` is `0`, should I not be adding 0s instead of 1s? Is the most significant bit actually `01`?

As a separate example, if a bit refers to the first two digits and not only the first, why is a right shift of 3 to the binary sequence `0111 0010`, `0000 1110`, instead of `1110 1110`?

Comment: Could you clarify exactly what the book says? Because you have different but sequences in title and beginning of the text and the end of the text. And a bit is one bit, not two

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Reformatted!

Comment: It should be 0000 1100, please verify again Or may be there could be a printing mistake.

Comment: 0b00110100 >> 3 = 0b00000110, as far as I know https://ideone.com/Nysq4f

Comment: Your book is wrong.

Comment: @arunpal So if the answer is 0000 1100, then would an arithmetic right shift to the binary sequence "0100 0100" also be "0000 1000"? The textbook says "1110 1000".

Comment: Yup right shift by 3 will be 0000 1000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Index : 76543210
a >> 0: 01100100
a >> 1: 00110010
a >> 1: 00011001
a >> 1: 00001100
```

Another example:

```
Index : 76543210
a >> 0: 10000100
a >> 1: 11000010
a >> 1: 11100001
a >> 1: 11110000
```

It is exactly as you believe it to be. An arithmetic shift, otherwise known as a signed shift, which already gives you a good hint at what it does, shifts the bits left or right, while preserving the signed bit and when moving right, replicates the signed bit.

Here is the formal definition:

> A shift, applied to the representation of a number in a fixed radix
>   numeration system and in a fixed-point representation system, and in
>   which only the characters representing the fixed-point part of the
>   number are moved. An arithmetic shift is usually equivalent to
>   multiplying the number by a positive or a negative integral power of
>   the radix, except for the effect of any rounding; compare the logical
>   shift with the arithmetic shift, especially in the case of
>   floating-point representation.

The Wikipedia entry has some good illustrative pictures: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_shift

Likely the author simply messed up his own example, wanting to show that it preserves the left-most bit (in most cases) and replicates it. Though he forgot to set it.